# Tableau dropdown set custom wordings instead of using default (All)

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

In the Tableau dropdown, the default option in dashboard output is (All).
Can I set custom wordings instead of using default (All)?
For example, I want to put (All inventories) instead of (All).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't (unfortunately).

A workaround could be to make a button with "All inventories" and make a filter action when users press on it.